# Excluding <h3> from strip_tags

Tags: php, strip-tags

I'm trying to simply exclude the `<h3>` tag in the strip_tags function. The result I'm getting is:

`<h>blabla</h3>`, instead of just `<h3>blabla</h3>`

The code:

```
$this->advertText = strip_tags($this->advertText, '<p><b><i><em><strong><br><ul><li><ol><dl><dd><dt><div><h3>');
```

So ... can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: I've tested it, and it works fine for me on PHPFiddle. Well, I had issues before when it stripped out a span tag, which it wouldn't suppose to strip out at all. So I just made my own function, as after thorough testing, I found strip_tags quite unreliable.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php There is a lot of negativity concerning its reliability.